# AWS Glue- how to write dynamic frame in S3 as .txt file and use '|' as the delimiter

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I want to write a dynamic frame to S3 as a text file and use '|' as the delimiter.

How can I modify the code below, so that Glue saves the frame as a .txt file and uses '|' as the delimiter.

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame = frame,
        connection_type = "s3",    
        connection_options = {"path": outpath},
        format = "csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a DynamicFrame to a spark dataframe and use spark write option sep to save it with your delimiter.

```
df=frame.toDf()
df.write.option("sep","|").option("header","true").csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why you want to write your data with `.txt` extension, but then in your file you specify `format="csv"`. If you meant as a generic text file, csv is what you want to use.

Glue DynamicFrameWriter supports custom format options, here's what you need to add to your code (also see docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html)):

```py
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=frame,
    connection_type='s3',
    connection_options={
        'path': outpath,
    },
    format='csv',
    format_options={
        'separator': "|"
        # ...other kwargs
    }
)
```

Please note that DynamicFrameWriter won't allow to specify a name for your file, and will also create multiple outputs based on the amount of partitions created during execution.

If you want just a single output file, you have to do:

```py
df = df.repartition(1)
```

before writing to s3.

Answer (score 0):

Glue does **not** support `.txt` as output currently. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html) you can read up on the supported file types.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Glue you can convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe, simply with:

```
pandasDF = sparkDF.toPandas()
```

and you can enjoy all the modern comforts of Pandas.